# How to retrieve dynamic type size data from chain extension in ink?

Tags: ink, smart-contract, chain-extension

my example looks like this :

```
#[ink(extension = 1111]
fn asset_name(asset_id: u32) -> Result<[u8], PalletAssetErr>
```

or this

```
fn asset_name(asset_id: u32) -> Result<[u8], PalletAssetErr> {
        ::ink_env::chain_extension::ChainExtensionMethod::build(1111u32)
            .input::<u32>()
            .output::<[u8]>()
            .handle_error_code::<PalletAssetErr>()
            .call(&asset_id)
```

and I got this error

> Result<[u8], PalletAssetErr> doesn't have a size known at compile-time

because [u8] has unknown size at compile time...

How to get dynamic size data on smart contract side?

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests, the size has to be known at compilation time. So, either sized arrays, or `ink_prelude::vec::Vec` is what you need.